# When a beta SE gets closed, make the data dump available on Area 51

Tags: feature-request, data-dump, beta-phase, closed-sites

When a beta SE gets closed, a data dump can be downloaded for a few days right after, then it's not possible to have access to the dump. It's annoying for several reasons:

- People who took part in the beta SE might want their data back and might miss the time window where they could download the dump;
- People who didn't take part in it could still be interested to read some Q&A on the site's topic;
- New beta SEs that have some overlapping interest with the closed SE could benefit from having access to the Q&A (understanding why it closed, what pitfalls they should avoid, and potentially copy the most interesting Q&A instead of starting from scratch);
- As a general principle, it's not great to remove user content.

I propose to add a link on each closed SE website's Area 51 page (e.g. [Big Data](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40518) ; [Artificial Intelligence](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57719/artificial-intelligence)) to retrieve the dump.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is *already done*. Closed proposals on Area51 are given a download link to the datadump.

At the top of the [Artificial Intelligence Area51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57719/artificial-intelligence) you see this banner:

> The AI site didn't have enough activity during the beta, and has been closed. You can download the [data dump of all questions here](http://sstatic.net/area51/datadumps/022014%20Artificial%20Intelligence.zip).

You can see this on [other](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11942/game-of-go) [long-closed](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/164/firearms) [proposals](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3303/sexuality) [too](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business).

Big Data is the *exception* here; I don't know why it doesn't have a data dump, perhaps it just had not generated enough data in it's mere 13 days of existence. Perhaps the missing banner is an oversight.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I got unlucky to run across Big Data first (and ironic that it didn't generate enough data).

Comment: What a strange coincedende that *Big Data* didn't generate enough data...