# Is there a way I can still gain access to answers from closed Literature site?

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-sites

I would like to obtain some answers to questions I have posted on now closed stack exchange Literature site. Is there still a way for me to do it?

Comment: Related: [When a beta SE gets closed, make the data dump available on Area 51](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234164)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can. On the [Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6426/literature), there is a link to the data dump. This data dump is a ZIP file containing XML files with information such as posts, for the Main and the Meta site. See the readme file in the data dump for more information.