# What happens to the content of a SE site that has been closed?

Tags: discussion, data-dump, beta-sites, creative-commons, closed-sites

The SE questions/answers are under the [CC BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) license ([ref](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/05/now-licensed-under-creative-commons/)). When a beta site does not make it and is closed, what happens to its content? Is it lost forever or is there a way to access the CC BY-SA content after the site closure?

Comment: Related (possible dupes?): [When a beta SE gets closed, make the data dump available on Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234164) | [Is there a way I can still gain access to answers from closed Literature site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238553)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some (most) of the beta sites have their data dump available after closure. If so, you can find a link to the data dump on their Area 51 page:

[image: Economics banner Area51]

Examples:

[1618 Economics](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1618/economics)
[2732 Atheism](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2732/atheism)
[3303 Sexuality](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3303/sexuality)
[23848 Theoretical Physics](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23848/theoretical-physics)
[44478 Gamification](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44478/gamification)

These pages are publicly available, without the need to log-in to either reach the site or download the data.

However, if the proposal was deleted instead of simply closed, no dump will be available. The entire proposal will be removed and a different banner will show on the proposal's page:

[image: Proposal deleted]

For more information on proposals, see the [Area 51 FAQ](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) and its [meta](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I think in the distant past, sites that got shut down in private beta didn't have a data dump published. Someone here asked a question about why the Big Data site didn't have a dump published.